# Change height of Support Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I'm using the `V7 support library` and I would like to change the **height** of action bars in certain activities only.

This is my `styles.xml` :

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style>

    <!-- here -->
    <style name="Double_Action_Bar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Double_Action_Bar_Style</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Double_Action_Bar_Style" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="height">@dimen/abc_action_bar_double_height</item>
        <item name="android:height">@dimen/abc_action_bar_double_height</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Where :

`@dimen/abc_action_bar_double_height == 2 * @dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height`

on my manifest file I'm including it like :

```
<application
    android:name="com.myapp.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:label=""
        android:theme="@style/Double_Action_Bar" /> <!-- here -->
```

But looks like `.Home`'s actionbar is not altered.

How can I edit the ActionBar height with `AppCompat` ? Any help would be very appreciated :)

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't do that.  There is a reason it is hard to do (it is supposed to stay the system standard height for continuity with the platform).

Comment: @Booger Thank you. So it can be updated without redesigning everything  ?

Answer (score 0):

In your styles.xml

```
<!-- Define a base Theme that inherits from the one you want (dark, light, light with Dark action bar... -->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat">
</style>
<!-- Create sub themes necessaries and edit the actionBar style for them -->
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="AppBaseTheme"> 
  <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyleBig</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme2" parent="AppBaseTheme">
  <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyleSmall</item>
</style>
<!-- Edit on any of them the height for actionBar -->
<style name="ActionBarStyleBig" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
  <item name="height">@dimen/bigActionBAr</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarStyleSmall" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
  <item name="height">@dimen/smallActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Please notice that in Api < 11, the height is specified as name="height" but in api>10 you need to use name="android:height" in order to make this work normally. This means that you need to create these themes also in the styles.xml located at folders values-v11 and values-v14 (and any other styles.xml that you may have).

In your manifest, just use the Theme you need:

```
<activity
  android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme1" >
</activity>
<activity
  android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.SecondActivity"
  android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme2>
```

Remember and recheck that you are not overriding this settings in any other styles.xml

Hope it helps. I tried it and worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `actionBarSize`

```
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="AppBaseTheme"> 
  <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/actionbar_height</item>
</style>
```